# Gnuplot generating weird graph for Fresnel equation

Tags: gnuplot, physics

I'm trying to generate graphs for Fresnel coefficients, but the graph is wrong.

```
#! /usr/bin/gnuplot -p

#Gnuplot script Fresnel equation
set term postscript eps enhanced color lw 2 "Arial" 20
set title "Fresnel do ar para vidro"
#set name for file
set output "fresnel.eps"
#Define refractive index middle 1
ni = 1
#Define refractive index middle 2
nt =  3/2
#Define constant
k = ni/nt
#Define conversion
TRAD = pi/180.0
#define cos, sin conversion
sind(x) = sin(x*TRAD)
cosd(x) = cos(x*TRAD)
#Define sqrt
sq(x) = sqrt( 1 - k**2 * sind(x)*sind(x) )
sqd(x) = sq(x*TRAD)
#R perpendicular
ri(x) = (ni*cosd(x) - nt*sqd(x)) / (ni*cosd(x) + nt * sqd(x))
#R paralelo
rii(x) = - (nt*cosd(x) - ni*sqd(x)) / (ni*sqd(x) + nt*cosd(x))
#Function
p(x) = (ri(x) - rii(x)) / (ri(x) + rii(x))

set ylabel "ress"
set xlabel "Angulo de incidencia"
set yrange [-1:2.5]
set autoscale x
#ploting graph
plot p(x), ri(x) with line, rii(x) w line
```

I need to get a graph like the link:

https://www.geogebra.org/m/wKk62nUk

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete solution, but a few remarks:

- `nt = 3/2` uses integer division and yields `nt = 1`. You want to have `nt = 3.0/2.0` or `nt = 1.5`.
- The angle arguments are multiplied by `TRAD`. This is a conversion from degrees to radians. Therefore the xrange should be set to something like `set xrange [0:90]`
- You have `sqd(x) = ...sq(x*TRAD)...`, `sq(x) = ...sind(x)...`, and `sind(x) = sin(x*TRAD)`. This chain multiplies the initial argument by `TRAD*TRAD`. Most probably you want to change `sq(x) = ...sind(x)...` to `sq(x) = ...sin(x)...`.

We get closer to the desired graph but we are not finished yet. I think you should double check the source equations.